# An issue of getAllResponseHeaders() in jQuery on IE 10.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

**Browser: IE 10.0.9200.16721**
This issue only happens on IE 10.

When I use function getAllResponseHeaders() of xmlHttpRequest object in jQuery, it will cause a error response header:

**The error header:** "\ncontent-type: application/json\r\n\r\n"

**Which should be :** "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nDate: Wed, 16 Oct 2013 05:07:11 GMT\r\n\r\n"

**The problems are:**

1) When parsing the header, we use "\r\n" to split, but here ""\ncontent-type..." will cause a parse error.

2) some items in header are missing.

Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13534444/1369055

Comment: Seems not the same issue. "Change the ajax type to "HEAD" instead of GET or POST and it should pull the response headers." I used GET to raise the ajax request already.